# Which `format` would be negotiated for REST request?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

There are three variants of format selection:

```
curl -uadmin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/hellouser.json"
curl -uadmin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/hellouser?format=json"
curl -uadmin:admin -H "Accept: text/html" "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/hellouser"
```

But this is unclear from the [DOC](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/) what format would be selected for next query:

```
curl -uadmin:admin -H "Accept: text/html" "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/hellouser.xml?format=json"
```

I expect `json` here.
May someone provide links to relevant specifications or documentation **which describes priority** how {format} negotiated? like this is described for `Rails`:

> Rails picks up the expected format from the query parameter format, or if not there from the URL path suffix, or it not there from the Accept header

**UPD**
The controller can handle all supplied formats: `json`, `xml`, `html`

**UPD**
Another corner case:

```
curl -uadmin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/hellouser.pl?format=json"
curl -uadmin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/hellouser.pl?format=xml"
```

Comment: hey, that's a clever question !

Comment: @Linovia: voteup ;-)

Comment: I think it'll be JSON, according to [sources](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a68b37d8bc432fae37ef5880aec500002b59f565/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L43)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd believe you wouldn't have a 200 response, only an error with content negotiation.

The code shows that:

1. `?format=json`(`format_query_param`) will be [discarded](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L44) by the `.xml` (`format_suffix`)
2. [filter available renderers](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L47) leaving only the `XMLRenderer` left
3. then it will [loop on the accept header](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L55) but none will match `text/html`
4. finally this will be down to the [exception](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L78)

Comment: I do not understand your answer. What is the priority for `format` negotiation? Is this right to expect `json`? Maybe I do not ask correctly. will fix question a bit.

Comment: My answer is, you will get a content negotiation error. XML will take over JSON but fail to comply to accepted text/html.

Comment: I'll update the django rest documentation later to make this clear :)

Comment: great. I vote up already. when you done I will apply your answer

Comment: Behavior described at paragraph one is not expeced: query parameter should take precedence over suffix. I have added another corner cases to the question. Also I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5893) with relevant links with description what precedence is used by other frameworks.